# AsyncStorage key value not able retrieve in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I am storing both username and password as key value async storage from main component.
In below  component  i am retrieving username and password from asyncstorage and stored as  state and pass them to  authentication for axios. But some how value received using state are always undefined. I  have notice through logs that i am retrieving correct value from asyncstorage. So despite assigning value to usestate ,i am receiving undefined value.
when i store both username and password in a variable and passed to axios ,it does works.

Any help would be highly appreciated

```
function Home(props) {
  const [username,setUsername]=useState();
  const [password,setPassword]=useState();
  const usernames ="abc";
  const passwords="123";

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const  value1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem("login");
      const value2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem("password");

      setUsername(value1);
      setPassword(value2);
      console.log("retrieved value from async storage  ",value1,value2 ); //both value are retrieved correctly 


      
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    getData();
    console.log("stored value ",username,password ); // state value as undefined 

    axios
      .post("https://........", {
        auth: {
          username:username,
          password:password,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [username,password]);
}
```

Comment: read more [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen   Hi Dean i would highly appreciate if you could help me with what i am doing wrong , i have already gone through this document and kind of clueless.

Comment: you aren't calling `getData()`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen can you please have al look at other issue

Comment: see my answer, for an update, it should work as you expect it to

Answer (score 0):

you aren't calling `getData()`, also only do your axios request once the username and password have been set to truethy values

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!username) return;
    if(!password) return;
    console.log("stored value ",username,password ); // state value as undefined 
    axios
    .post("https://........", {
      auth: {
        username:username,
        password:password,
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, [username,password]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to move the axios request inside another useEffect that only runs when the username and password are updated:

```js
function Home(props) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem("login");
      const value2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem("password");

      setUsername(value1);
      setPassword(value2);
      console.log("retrieved value from async storage  ", value1, value2); 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []); // empty dependency array means this effect will run once when the component mounts

  useEffect(() => {
    if (username && password) { // only run if both username and password are set
      console.log("stored value ", username, password);

      axios
        .post("https://........", {
          auth: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
          },
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }, [username, password]); // this effect will run when username or password state changes
}
```

Comment: The issue is that setting state in React using useState is asynchronous, so when you are setting the username and password state and immediately trying to log or use them, they might not be updated yet.